# osascript: can't open default scripting component

Tags: node.js, applescript, osascript

I run the following nodejs code to execute apple script:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')
exec('osascript -e \'return "hello" \'', (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
})
```

I'm basically trying to run AppleScript in NodeJS and probably use it with Electron in the future to do some task. The code should log "hello" in the console, but it doesn't.

Here's the output:

```
Error: Command failed: osascript -e 'return "hello" '
osascript: can't open default scripting component.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:319:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:441:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: `osascript -e 'return "hello" '`
}
```

The error message doesn't look like any JavaScript errors, so it's probably not the problem in my code. A Google search doesn't show anything that fixes my problem. I tried restarting my machine, and it doesn't help. I tried to run the code directly in node console and it also doesn't work. Directly running the shell command in terminal works. I don't know what the problem is and how can I fix it.

---

**Edit:** I've also tried quoting the `exec` command as follows, however the same error occurs:

```
...
exec("osascript -e 'return \"hello\"'", (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
  ...
})
```

---

**Edit 2:** I tried putting the osascript executive file in my project directory, and run the following code:

```
exec("./osascript -e 'return \"hello\"'", (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
  if (err){console.error(err)};
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
})
```

It still spits out the same error message. Also, I finally understand what scripting component is. Basically, when a user run script int the terminal, it is passed tot he executive. It then pass it to the scripting component (located /System/Library/Components/AppleScript.component) to interpret the code and execute it. Somehow node trick osascript into thinking the scripting component doesn't exist? I mean I checked the scripting component installation and everything is good.

Comment: Did you had audio plugins installed on the machine? It seems some of them can cause this issue.